# Where are the drawings for wo2004066851a2

Tags: patent-drawings, wo2004066851

I have an invention that I want to patent, but it sounds similar to wo2004066851a2. I'm hoping that the drawings of wo2004066851a2 will be helpful to me in figuring out whether this is what I am trying to patent so that I don't go forward with mine. 
Understanding the explanations and the claims of wo2004066851a2 is impossible without seeng the drawings.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. I am assuming you are looking at the Google patents page for WO2004066851, a PCT document. Unlike U.S. patent documents, google doesn't include a direct link to download PDFs of PCT application. It does include a link to the page for this application on WIPO's PatentScope, the home of PCT applications. There you will see the front page of the document. There are tabs above it including one for drawings. Also, the style in Ask Patents, and all other Stack Exchange sites, is to not have signatures in questions or answers, so for educational purposes I have removed yours.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "http://worldwide.espacenet.com/" and find the application, and find the drawings under "Mosaics"(there are two pages of drawings).

I am not sure is it acceptable to provide a direct link in Ask patents, otherwise I could provide the direct link.

:-)